# What is the best way to implement a variable-sized multi-line UITableCell?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to display a table full of twitter statuses (yes, this is the [Stanford Presence 2](http://cs193p.stanford.edu/downloads/AssignmentPresence2.pdf) assignment), which are variably sized.  I can relatively easily determine the appropriate height for my rows with code that approximates (from [accompanying lecture 9](http://cs193p.stanford.edu/downloads/09-TableViews.pdf)):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSString *text = ...;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:...];
    CGSize withinSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.width, 1000];
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:withinSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return size.height + somePadding;
}
```

I have tried two approaches (and some tweaks to both) to get a multi-line word-wrapping field of text into my table row.

1. Add a UILabel as a subview to my custom UITableCell subclass, and set the `numberOfLines` property to either a calculated number based on the height above (say, 6), or to 0 (theoretically unlimited).  The `numberOfLines` is ignored; I see either 1 or 2 lines, and no more.
2. Add a read-only UITextView as a subview.  This has the problem that the UITextView eats my scrolling; I end up scrolling inside a UITextView row instead of moving smoothly from row to row.  If I disable scrolling on the UITextView, I end up being unable to scroll at all.

This is a pretty common thing to do; what's the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the `UITextView`. That should allow input to be passed through to the `UITableView` so you get scrolling.

Comment: That seems to work, with scrolling disabled.  I think somewhere my UITextView is not getting appropriately sized though.

Comment: Yeah, eventually was able to get the right autosizing set of parameters to make that work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a blog I posted on this subject. I used a UILabel with numberOfLInes = 0. I hope this will be of some help.

[Sample Project with Variable Sized UITableViewCell](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/)

Answer (score 0):

While playing with userInteractionEnabled=NO, scrollEnabled=NO, and getting the right autosizing parameters set in IB worked, I think that going with a UILabel with numberOfLines=0 and the same autosizing parameters is ultimately a better idea, for the next person.